# Getting 2 values of focal length when finding Intrinsic camera matrix (F not Fx,Fy)?

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, camera-intrinsics

The following image is the example that was given in my computer vision class. Now I cant understand why we are getting 2 unique values of f. I can understand if mxf and myf are different, but shouldn't the focal length 'f' be the same?

[image: Camera intrinsic matrix found using matlab]

Comment: that's a weird formulation. where did you get this from? they probably just want to suggest that f, calculated from each of both figures, has a slightly different result.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thats exactly what I am wondering. Why is f calculated from both of the values different?

Comment: did you expect two _measurements_ to agree _exactly_? both numbers differ by ~0.26% which is a fairly good measurement error.

Comment: That part implicitly includes "aspect ratio". (They should be written as separately like fx and fy.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an Fx and a Fy. This is so that the the matrix transforms on f can scale f in two directions x and y. IIRC this is why you get 2 f numbers

Comment: no, that's what the `mx` and `my` are for, to describe the resolution of the sensor.

Comment: "Now I cant understand why we are getting 2 unique values of f" OP is talking about f, which is the way (more freedom) to scale f

Answer (score 0):

If really single `f` wanted, it should be modeled in the camera model used in calibration.
e.g. give the `mx`,`my` **as constants** to the camera model, and estimate the `f`.

However, perhaps the calibration process that obtained that `K` was not that way, but treated the two elements (`K(0,0)` and `K(1,1)`) **independently**.

In other words, `mx` and `my` were also estimated in the sense of dealing with the aspect ratio.
The estimation result is not the same as the values of `mx` and `my` calculated from the sensor specifications.

This is why you got 2 values.

Comment: I wrote "In other words, ...", but of course the calibration process doesn't really deal with `mx`, `my`. "The value of `K(0,0)` should be `mx * f`", is just your assuming.